# Customized KIM feauture selection function

Tags: r, function, apply, nmf

The function extractFeatures from `NMF` `package` can select features using the following method only if the features fulfill both following criteria are retained:

score greater than `\hat{\mu} + 3 \hat{\sigma}`, where `\hat{\mu}` and `\hat{\sigma}` are the median and the median absolute deviation (MAD) of the scores respectively;

the maximum contribution to a basis component is greater than the median of all contributions (i.e. of all elements of W).

How can I write this function in R that only applies the first criteria to data matrix?

Kim H and Park H (2007). "Sparse non-negative matrix factorizations via alternating non-negativity-constrained least squares for microarray data analysis." *Bioinformatics (Oxford, England)*, *23*(12), pp. 1495-502. ISSN 1460-2059, , .

Comment: So given a vector `scores`, you want to check which of its components are greater than `median(scores) + MAD(scores)`? If not, be more specific and see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1320535

Comment: Yes @Julius. It should be  + 3 times MAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a vector `scores`, the condition for each score can be checked as follows:

```
scores <- rnorm(5)
scores > (median(scores) + 3 * mad(scores))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

where we don't need to look for a function for MAD as `mad` from the package `stats` does exactly that. Now if you want to select corresponding columns from some matrix `M`, you could write simply

```
M[, scores > (median(scores) + 3 * mad(scores))]
```

And if you prefer a function for that, then you may use

```
featureCriterion <- function(M, scores)
  M[, scores > (median(scores) + 3 * mad(scores))]
```